# symfony2 translation sonata admin bunle

Tags: symfony, translation, bundle, admin, sonata-admin

I tried to translate Sonata Admin Bundle Breadcrumbs and Tablename List headline.
So far nothing worked :-(

I put my own translation files in /app/Resources/translations and in the translations folder of my own bundle. I tried to put them in SonataAdminBundle.de.yml and messages.de.yml. I also set a translation domain in my Admin class. 
But still I cannot see my own translation. The only translation file that is used is the one from the SonataAdminBundle.

Can anyone show me how to handle the translation for SonataAdminBundle correctly?
What files have to be placed where and what has to be the content of these files?

Thanks in advance.

Lisa

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is how i do it:

In my XYBundle, i create a XYBundle.fr.xliff file in XYBundle/Ressources/translations ( make sure it's translation and not Translation. Nothing worked for me with a T ) 
With at least one translation :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="" >
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="breadcrumb.link_article_list">
                <source>breadcrumb.link_article_list</source>
                <target>Liste des articles</target>
            </trans-unit>  
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

In your service declaration:

```
 <call method="setTranslationDomain">
            <argument>"XYBundle"</argument>
        </call>
```

And don't forget clearing your cache
php app/console cache:clear

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have cleared the cache. Otherwise new translation will be ignored.

In my case it still works with yaml and xml files together. But make sure the $translationDomain is set. Otherwise only the default SonataAdmin translation file will be loaded.

You can set the property manually in all sonata admin classes:

`protected $translationDomain = 'messages';`

or in the service declartion as shown above...